# How do I import a SysML model (in XMI format) to Papyrus?

Tags: eclipse, modeling, xmi, sysml

I have an XMI 2.1 formatted SysML model, exported from Enterprise Architect.

I'm evaluating [Papyrus](http://www.papyrusuml.org/scripts/home/publigen/content/templates/show.asp?P=128&L=EN&ITEMID=12) as an alternate model IDE. I'd like to import my XMI file into Papyrus, including all structural and behavioral blocks.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Create a new Papyrus project.
2. Right-click on project, select Import, and browse to my XMI file.

However, this just includes the XMI file in the Papyrus project. If I open it, I see the model elements as XML.

Does Papyrus support importing XMI, and if so, how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked through a similar problem recently, though with UML, so your mileage may vary.

I solved it with a hint regarding the Eclipse EMF from here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=606949&S=333b8c3faacad6b950cf6247312f9c3e

Since SysML is a dialect of UML2, you should be able to create a new EMF project; and in the project creation wizard, you will be presented with the option to import your XMI file.

Comment: On Eclipse June, whenever I try to import a XMI file in this way I always get the error message: "An error ocurred while performing this operation."