# Import XMI files exported by Sparx Enterprise Architect - EAJAVA... types

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, eclipse-emf, xmi

Is there a way to deal with the EAJAVA_.. types like EAJAVA_INT in eclipse emf plugin?

There is an exception thrown while importing the xmi file:

org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.UnresolvedReferenceException: Unresolved reference 'EAJava_int'.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to use common tags, or you may not get answers.

Comment: What would be common tags for this question? Can you give me an advice?

Comment: I've already added them :) If you point at the tags you can see the number of "followers" normally a pretty good indication of the popularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a recommendation made for a similar question: [How do I import a SysML model (in XMI format) to Papyrus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651380/how-do-i-import-a-sysml-model-in-xmi-format-to-papyrus)

That approach requires creating a new *EMF* project, and importing an XMI file during the creation of that project. I'm working with Eclipse Juno, and I don't see that option occurring with the current EMF bundles.

I've read [that XMI import isn't supported currently supported with Papyrus](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/238299/813124/).

As an alternative, for UML modeling in an Eclipse platform, there's [Modelio (Free Edition available)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/modeliouml) which is apparently based on Eclipse. [Modelio supports XMI Import/Export with the addition of a particular Modelio module](http://archive.modeliosoft.com/en/support/forum/1-general/545-the-modelio-free-xmi-exportimport-feature.html).

My only concern with Modelio is that although it appears to be based on Eclipse, but it doesn't install via an Update site - one has to install the whole Modelio bundle, and maintain it separate from one's primary Eclipse IDE. It is, at least, a free alternative for UML modeling in the Eclipse IDE, such that would support XMI import/export. There's also [a video tutorial available, demonstrating how to use Eclipse stand-alone and Modelio on the same project, simultaneously.](http://archive.modeliosoft.com/video/tutorial-1.2.html)

I'd found this question while trying answer a similar question that I'd encountered, myself. I was looking at the idea of using [the Sparx Systems XSD Datatypes Package](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/xml_technologies/xsd_datatype_package.htm), in a project. That package from Sparx Systems is provided in XMI format. It's been an informative process, to determine an answer to that, and I thought I may as well share what I'd found. I suppose I'll be switching to Modelio, shortly. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: After installing  Modelio Free Edition, however, I'm afraid I'm unable to find the XMI Import/Export Module. It's not showing up at the Modelio Store, either. Perhaps it's been moved into one of their not-for-free editions...

Comment: It looks like they've updated how XMI models are imported into Modelio. One can simply right-click on the model in the 'Model' view in Modelio, then select XMI -> Import - easy peasy ;)